# Selenium Webdriver wait for url?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium Webdriver script, written in python that opens a url;

```
def GotToURL(self):

  #Go to url
  driver.get("http://someurl.com")

  #Prints url once it is finished loading
  print driver.current_url
```

Problem is that 1 out of every 15, the url wont finish loading. So, all i want to add is a step that tries to run the step

```
 print driver.current_url
```

for 10 seconds and if it doesn't work, restart the script.

Anyone any ideas?

Running Selenium Webdriver and python 2.7 on osx

Comment: This isn't quite as simple as you point out. The fact the URL changes isn't an indication the **page** has finished loading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Arran. I had feared as much. The problem i am facing is that the rest of the script won't continue until the page is finally loaded. If i click the top button on the browser, the script continues as normal but having to do that kind of defeats the purpose of test automation.

Comment: Your page probably has some content added by AJAX calls that need some extra time to finish. You'll need to set up some explicit [wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#waits) according to your needs.

Comment: @jJavier thanks for the reply. I'm not sure it is that as this loading event happens randomly and it never finishes loading (i've left it over night before). I've tried using waits (using element_is_clickable) but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

The best option I can think of is to use the [Explicit and Implicit Waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

You could for example define the driver like this

```
driver = webdriver.Ie() #note that I'm using IE
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10) #set the max to 10s
```

and then put your action in a try except statement, specifying a TimeoutException. Doing like this you are saying that if the page takes more than 10 seconds to load, the driver must throw the exception, and then you can define how to handle this situation.

Comment: thanks for the reply.

Unfortunately, i'm falling at the first hurdle of your solution in that i can't seem to get the exception working correctly.


`from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

DRIVER.set_page_load_timeout(5)

DRIVER.get(http://url.com)

try:
    print DRIVER.current_url
except TimeoutException:
    print 'Page failed to load`

When load timeouts out, "Page failed to load" is not being printed.

Instead, 

`selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: u'Timed out waiting for page load.`

Any ideas? Am i doing anything obviously wrong?

Comment: @user1799835 you're welcome. Is during the get that the exception is thrown, so you have to insert that line inside the try scope in order to obtain what you want.